# Python: ensuring all subclass methods return the same thing

Tags: python, inheritance

In Python 3, I have class `Animal` as an abstract base class, with abstract method `give_name(self)`. Derived classes include `Dog` and `Cat`.

The start of the contents of `give_name()` method can can differ across subclasses. For example, in the `Dog` subclass, there might be `print("bark")` while in the `Cat` subclass, there may be `print("meow")`.

However, I want to make sure that in all derived classes, `give_name()` ends with `return self.__class__.__name__`. How can I enforce this constraint (as elegantly as possible)?

Current Code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class Animal(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def give_name(self):
        pass

class Dog(Animal):
    def give_name(self):
        print("bark")
        return self.__class__.__name__

class Cat(Animal):
    def give_name(self):
        print("meow")
        return self.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: can probably be achieved with a decorator or a metaclass, depends on the actual use case. Provide a [mcve] if you want a more detailed answer

Comment: Thanks. Added my current code.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement `give_name()` in the superclass, but delegate the print part to subclasses, e.g.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    def give_name(self):
        self.print()
        return self.__class__.__name__

    @abstractmethod
    def print(self):
        pass

class Dog(Animal):
    def print(self):
        print("bark")

class Cat(Animal):
    def print(self):
        print("meow")
```

Comment: Good point. I'll probably add checks (e.g. through __init_subclass__ or by using metaclasses) to make sure that derived classes have the print() method.

Comment: @wwl That part is easy: make `print` the abstract method defined in `Animal`. The more important part is to ensure that no subclass *overrides* `give_name`.

Comment: That would still not prevent subclasses from implementing their own `give_name` that return whatever they what. Maybe OP should wait for `@final` in Python 3.8 :)